# iPhone application to save data over the network into central database

Tags: iphone

I am new to iOS development. How to save data (say user information) over the network into central database? My application will take user information and store it into central database.

Comment: I've asked a similar question which may help you [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943597/how-should-i-architect-my-iphone-app-to-talk-to-my-website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a trivial 'the answer is this...' kind of questions.

For what it is worth, you would need to set up some form of server application - perhaps using a web MVC framework like Rails, Django, Grails, ASP.NET MVC - providing a nice RESTful interface to some backend database, passing data around in JSON documents.

Here is a reference to the iOS API end of things:

[URL Loading System](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i)

Since you are using PHP - you might want to write a RESTful API for the database operations you require.  A SO question about this is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973156/how-to-write-a-rest-api)

And here is a tutorial describing how to create an API in PHP for an online leaderboard - which should get you started:

[Online Leaderboard for iPhone game in PHP](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/10/29/iphone-coding-tutorial-creating-an-online-leaderboard-for-your-games/)

Comment: He is correct... most choose to use a PHP script on your server that updates an MySQL database... at least I do.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.. My concern is i have a website. database is sql server database. now i want to make a iphone application which stores users data(information like name, city) into same database or i have to create another database? to do this is there any useful tutorial. i am concern like shall i use sqlite or core data etc.

Comment: There's no reason why it can't go into the same database.  Core data and sqlite (in this context) relates to client side storage, so the phone/pod/pad side.  As for a tutorial - if you told me what technology the existing server side is written in, that could help.

Comment: @iandotkelly- Central database is MySql. so i just want using application people can fill there details (that is easy) and those details then subbmit to central database. mysql in my case

Comment: What technology is the website written in.

Comment: PHP and MySql. with due respect to your question i think technology of website doesnot matter. what matter is central database and technology to use for  transfer of data from iphone devices over the network..

Comment: No the website technology is critical here, you i'm not aware of a way to connect to a server side MySql database directly from iOS - the way most people do this is via a webservice - i.e. effectively via a website.  So the iPhone hits the website with a specific URL - to retrieve or update records in the database.

Comment: ok fine understood. so my application will hit the website. but how it will save data there? Can you please explain it more. Any tutorial or advice. n yah i really appriciate your replies. God Bless you

Comment: I am not a PHP expert - so I've found and attached a link to a tutorial in my answer to your question.  Good luck.